# Take mean of points within a radius using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

Is it possible to derive for every point in a shape file the spatial mean of all points within a radius of x km from that point in ArcGIS?

At the moment I can only find the point to raster tool which converts all points within a given pixel size to give the spatial mean, but I'd like to use circles instead of pixels.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to specify the license level(s) available. It certainly possible; with an Advanced seat, the Near command can be used for this, otherwise you might need a modest bit of Python.

Comment: If you don't have 100*1000s point, create buffers and intersect them with points, output - points. Summarise output, case field - polygon id. It's even simpler than generate near table, advanced license.